# How to split a string using regex?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I'm trying to split the ad_content with each "_" character, but I don't know why I can't go further than the 9th split word (`splits[SAFE_OFFSET(8)] AS objective`).

This is the query I'm using:

```sql
SELECT
    ad_content,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS country,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS product,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS budget,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS source,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS campaign,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] AS audience,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(6)] AS route_type,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(7)] AS business,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(8)] AS objective,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(9)] AS format,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(10)] AS nnn,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(11)] AS date,
FROM (
  SELECT
    AD_CONTENT,
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(
            AD_CONTENT,
            r'([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(.+)',
            r'\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8|\9|\10|\11|\12'),
          '|') AS splits
  FROM ga_digital_marketing
```

For example, ad_content = `us_latam_perf_facebook_black-friday_bbdd-push_SCL-CCP_domestic_conversion_push_all_20210906`

And this is the results using the query from above:

| ad_content | country | product | budget | source | campaign | audience | route_type | business | objective | format | nnn | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| us_latam_perf_facebook_black-friday_bbdd-push_SCL-CCP_domestic_conversion_push_all_20210906 | us | latam | perf | facebook | black-friday | bbdd-push | SCL-CCP | domestic | conversion | **us0** | **us1** | **us2** |

As you can see above, from the  format column (`splits[SAFE_OFFSET(9)] AS format`) are not giving the results correctly.

I believe that the problem is in here: `r'\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8|\9|\10|\11|\12')` because maybe  the number 0 of |\10 is not recognizing it as a number but as a string. And that's why I have as a result **us0** **us1** and **us2**

Is there a solution for this limitation?

Is there another way to split the ad_content example?

Comment: Right, `\n` backreference syntax usually supports groups from 1 to 9. Try `$10`, `$11` and `$12`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the comment. But it didn't worked. The console shows me this: " Invalid REGEXP_REPLACE pattern: Rewrite schema error: '\' must be followed by a digit or '\' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery's REGEXP_REPLACE supports only  \1 to \9 - that is why!

> Is there a solution for this limitation?

Use below approach instead

```
SELECT
    -- ad_content,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS country,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS product,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS budget,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS source,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] AS campaign,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(5)] AS audience,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(6)] AS route_type,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(7)] AS business,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(8)] AS objective,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(9)] AS format,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(10)] AS nnn,
    splits[SAFE_OFFSET(11)] AS date,
FROM (
  SELECT
    AD_CONTENT,
    SPLIT(AD_CONTENT, '_') AS splits
  FROM ga_digital_marketing
)
```

if applied to sample in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer :o)